# Problem mapping operator

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, map-operator

I'm trying to write a mapping that will copy the text and automatically unwrap it at the same time. Here's what I got:

```
function! CopyUnwrapped(type, ...)
    if a:0
        normal! gv"ay
    else
        normal! `[v`]"ay
    endif
    new
    setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile nobuflisted
    normal! "ap
    %normal! vipJ
    normal! ggvG$"+y
    q
endfunction

vnoremap <leader>y :call CopyUnwrapped(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
nnoremap <leader>y :set opfunc=CopyUnwrapped<CR>g@
```

It works almost perfectly… works fine in visual mode as far as I can tell. But when I try `<leader>yip`, for instance, the last line of the paragraph is cut off, I don't understand why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at example in documentation for [`g@`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#g@), you can notice that your function is missing handling of a linewise selection. `ip` motion apparently acts as a linewise in this case and if you handle it as characterwise only first character of the last line is copied (because that's where `` `] `` is positioned; do `vipv` on a paragraph to see it for yourself).

Thus that `if`-statement should look like this:

```
if a:0
    normal! gv"ay
elseif a:type == 'line'
    normal! `[V`]"ay
else
    normal! `[v`]"ay
endif
```

Notice that for linewise selection, `V` is used to select by lines (which quotes are used is irrelevant for this kind of selection).

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you. :) When I read the documentation I thought that was only necessary if you wanted to do something different when the selection is linewise, but I didn't care and I thought the `\`]` mark would record the exact position. Anyway, now I get it, thanks.